# save both field same name relationship one to one backpack laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have two tables with relationship one to one hasOne and have column same name

```
    CRUD::addField([
        'label'     => "Title",
        'type'      => 'text',
        'name'      => 'new_title', // the db column for the foreign key
    ]);
    CRUD::addField([
        'label'     => "Title",
        'type'      => 'text',
        'name'      => 'achive.new_title', // the db column for the foreign key
        'entity'    => 'achive',
    ]);
```

I just want show once but save both to two table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something that's call the callbacks method, the simplicity of that method is you can control what you want after `create`, `edit`, `delete` and `etc`.

So, in your controller just need one field name,

```
CRUD::addField([
    'label'     => "Title",
    'type'      => 'text',
    'name'      => 'new_title',
]);
```

After that, you can create a new trait in your controller for creating/updating your relationship,

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
```

And then, declare the store function,

```
public function store() {

    // Get the value from the request
    $request = $this->crud->getRequest();

    // And then you can insert/update data into your relationship table
    \DB::table('achives') // Your relation table
        ->updateOrInsert(
            ['new_title' => $request->new_title], 
            ['other_column_name' => 'Value of your other column']
        );

    $response = $this->traitStore();
    // do something after save
    return $response;
}
```

The `updateOrInsert` method accepts two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the record, and an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns to be updated. [more info here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-or-insert)